# Locationmanager doesn't give me location on some devices e.g HTC Desire 626 or QMobile,

Tags: android, google-maps, location, google-play-services, android-gps

But all other devices are getting correct location, There is a strange behavior that google maps and whatsapp are getting exact location in HTC desire but my app doesn't get location. Please help me, this behavior creates a lot of problems for me. Please help as early as possible.

```
  public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {

    private final Context mContext;

    // flag for GPS status
    boolean isGPSEnabled = false;

    // flag for network status
    boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

    // flag for GPS status
    boolean canGetLocation = false;

    Location location; // location
    double latitude; // latitude
    double longitude; // longitude

    // The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
    private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10; // 10 meters

    // The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
    private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1; // 1 minute

    // Declaring a Location Manager
    protected LocationManager locationManager;

    private static final int REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSION_LOCATION = 4;

    String mPermission = Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION;

    public GPSTracker(Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;
        getLocation();
    }



    public Location getLocation() {
        try {
            locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

            // getting GPS status
            isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

            // getting network status
            isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
                // no network provider is enabled
            } else {
                this.canGetLocation = true;
                // First get location from Network Provider

                // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
                if (isGPSEnabled) {
                    if (location == null) {
                        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission((Activity)mContext, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                            // TODO: Consider calling
                            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                            //                                          int[] grantResults)
                            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                            try {

                                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) mContext, new String[]{mPermission},
                                            REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSION_LOCATION);
                                    // If any permission above not allowed by user, this condition will execute every time, else your else part will work

                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            return null;
                        }
                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);

//                        Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
//                        if (locationManager != null) {
//                            location = locationManager
//                                    .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
//
//                            if (location != null) {
//                                latitude = location.getLatitude();
//                                longitude = location.getLongitude();
//                            }
//                        }

                        if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                            if (location == null) {
                                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);

                                Log.d("Network", "Network");
                                if (locationManager != null) {
                                    location = locationManager
                                            .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

                                    if (location != null) {
                                        latitude = location.getLatitude();
                                        longitude = location.getLongitude();
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        if (location==null){
                            try {
                                location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(locationManager.getBestProvider(new Criteria(), true));
                            } catch(NullPointerException e) {}
                            if (location != null) {
                                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                                longitude = location.getLongitude();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (location==null){
            location=new Location("");
            location.setLatitude(0);
            location.setLongitude(0);
            return location;
        }else
            return location;
    }

    /**
     * Stop using GPS listener
     * Calling this function will stop using GPS in your app
     * */

    public void stopUsingGPS(){
        if(locationManager != null){
            locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Function to get latitude
     * */

    public double getLatitude(){
        if(location != null){
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
        }

        // return latitude
        return latitude;
    }

    /**
     * Function to get longitude
     * */

    public double getLongitude(){
        if(location != null){
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
        }

        // return longitude
        return longitude;
    }

    /**
     * Function to check GPS/wifi enabled
     * @return boolean
     * */

    public boolean canGetLocation() {
        return this.canGetLocation;
    }

    /**
     * Function to show settings alert dialog
     * On pressing Settings button will lauch Settings Options
     * */

    public void showSettingsAlert(){
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

        // Setting Dialog Title
        alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is settings");

        // Setting Dialog Message
        alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");

        // On pressing Settings button
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        // on pressing cancel button
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        // Showing Alert Message
        alertDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        latitude=location.getLatitude();
        latitude=location.getLongitude();
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

getLocation() always returns null object on HTC desire 626 model.

Build.gradel (App:level)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.bingoit.blaze"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 2
        versionName "1.1"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile files('libs/ksoap2-android-assembly-3.6.2-jar-with-dependencies.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'net.bohush.geometricprogressview:geometricprogressview:1.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:percent:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.6'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.weiwangcn.betterspinner:library-material:1.1.0'
    compile 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:2.0.0'
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I'd strongly recommend reading [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and particularly the page linked from there - [How to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example], then editing your question to take account of the advice in those pages. The amount of code you've posted, together with the request to "Please help as early as possible" are unlikely to encourage people to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added permissions to the APP MANIFEST FILE?

```
android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
```

or

```
 android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
```

Comment: of course added, I can get  location almost all devices except HTC desire 626 and QMobile

Comment: don't you think that the problem is device specific?... rather hardware problem!